# Nuxt: When using Github Pages with Custom Domain it is unable to access _nuxt folder

Tags: nuxt.js, github-pages

I have a static Nuxt based website. I wish to use the static website on github. However, I want to keep the nuxt development folder as a private repo and the dist part as a public folder.

1. Hence I created two github projects: `site-pvt` and `site-public`.
2. Using the pvt folder I created the website. I have tested it in local using `npm run generate` followed by `npm run start`. It works as expected.
3. I copy the `dist` directory from the `site-pvt` to `site-public`.
4. I push the `site-public` to github where I set the pages to the main branch
5. When I type URL `https://<username>.github.io/site-public` I am able to see the site as I do local

However

6. When I set a custom domain in github in the `site-public` repo, it seems to be that the HTML is retrieved but the Javascript access to the `_nuxt` directory is unavailable.

Following are some relevant information

```
// nuxt.config.js
export default {
  target: 'static',

  router: {
    base: '/public-site/'
  },
  ..
}
```

The directory structure of the `dist` directory is as follows:

```
.
└── _nuxt
    ├── 00e716f.js
└── .nojekyll
├── posts
└── 404.html
├── favicon.ico
├── CNAME
├── index.html
```

There must be some other setting to be done to get this working. I will appreciate any help on this. Thanks

Comment: Your repository route is `/site-public`, while your `router.base` property inside nuxt.config.js is set to `/public-site`.

Answer (score 0):

The error is in the router settings of nuxt.config.js. It should be set to `/` which is the default

```
// nuxt.config.js
export default {
  target: 'static',

  router: {
    base: '/'
  },
  ..
}
```

I should have realised this because the reason for putting the repo-name is that all repos are under the `<username>.github.io` domain and the router settings sets the base path to that repo. Such a setting is obviously not required when using a custom domain.